# system() call alternative on Windows CE 6.0 Platform

Tags: embedded, windows-ce

I need to run a local application on a windows CE 6.0 platform I am doing some work on.

Basically, *ALL* I need to do is run a command line application with a few arguments. I don't really even need to see the return value.

Basically, I have a little closed-source CE program which interacts with some specialized hardware, and I'm trying to control said hardware from within the software I am working on. Once I have everything set up, I am interacting with the hardware through it's API, but there are a few configuration settings which the API neglects to expose, and I need to alter to make everything work correctly (I'm working on getting the manufacturer to fix the API, but I need a working prototype soon).

Everything I have read says the system() call is what I need, but it does not seem to be present in Windows CE's stdlib.h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ShellExecuteEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms942611.aspx) seems to be available, as does [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms939168.aspx), if `ShellExecuteEx` isn't sufficient (and it should be), `CreateProcess` definitely will be, if a bit more work.

Comment: I got ShellExecuteEx working. How did you find this function? I spend a few hours looking through the MSDN docs, and couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: You couldn't find ShellExecuteEx in particular, or you couldn't find "a function" that did what you want? For the latter, experience in Windows-land, for the former, I searched for it specifically.

Comment: The former. I have very little windows experience, only embedded MCUs and some python.